# wav file audio samples are signed, how does DAC deal with signed numbers when it does not have negative supply?

Tags: pic, dac, floating-point

I was looking into wav audio file specification, they may hold the pulse coded modulation data as signed our unsigned integers as well as floating point values.

How does a DAC deal with signed numbers? Do they need a dual supply to output signed numbers?

What would be an appropriate way to convert floating point numbers into integer when sending them to DAC? I assume e.g conversion onto 8 bit would be simply multiplying by 255 but I am not sure since floating point numbers are signed.

Yes I realise that there are multiple types of ADCs.

Comment: I think the most sane option for a DAC is to be fed with unsigned numbers that divide up V- to V+ into their steps.

Comment: That seems to be what they do, at least for the ones I looked at.

Comment: Negative numbers do not necessarily mean negative voltages!

Comment: I guess you would have to bias the inputs for the DAC, so that 0 stays in half of your interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio is inherently AC.  That means the DC level doesn't matter and can be arbitrarily subtracted off and something else added.  In fact, frequencies below 20 Hz can be arbitrarily eliminated even in "HiFi" audio.

The WAV file is specifying the audio signal values as if the signal had zero DC offset.  That makes sense when you think about it, as it's the logical choice for communicating arbitrary audio signals.

However, that does not mean your D/A converter needs to produce negative voltages.  If the D/A converter has a output range of 0-5 V, for example, then you simply declare the midpoint of 2.5 V to be the WAV file zero level.

Note that this is little different from the arbitrary scaling you need to apply and that you don't seem to have a problem with.  You scale the min to max WAV file values for whatever representation that WAV file uses, to linearly map to the D/A output range.  There is no special case because one or both of these ranges include negative values.  Either way it's still just a simple linear scaling with offset.

In the case of a 0-5 V A/D, the midpoint is 2.5 V, which represents the audio zero level.  If the A/D is followed by a amplifier, then it will alter this range again.  Eventually a power amplifier driving speakers will eliminate the average DC level so there is no net DC going to the speakers.

Electrically, DC is easily eliminated from a audio signal by a *high pass filter*, which can be as simple as a capacitor in series followed by a resistor to ground.

Comment: Are you trying to say that I should just add a mid point value do the signed value cannot go below 0 at all? The 2s complement and the unsigned coding method do not merely differ by a DC level that can be added to convert one to the other

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have a DAC with a reference of 2.5V operating from a single supply (i.e. the full span output is 2.5V) that accepts 2s complement encoded values at the digital input.

The zero point in such a device is at \$\frac {V_{span}} 2\$ or 1.25V in this particular application.

If a device takes 2s complement as an input, then the values below 0 are encoded as less than the mid-span voltage; specifically, \$V_{out} = V_{midspan} + Code_{in} * V_{bit}\$ where \$V_{bit}\$ is the resolution; \$ V_{bit} = \frac {V_{span}} {2^n}\$ where n is the number of bits for the converter.

\$V_{code}\$ is the *signed* value of the input.

Note that on a split supply (+/- 2.5V for example) midspan is 0V.

There is an excellent [application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa042a/sbaa042a.pdf) that explains the various types of data formats used by DACs and ADCs.

Floating point numbers would normally be converted to integers within the range of the converter for a DAC. ADCs universally (all the ones I have seen) output fixed point values.

There are complex devices that have DSPs inside that can do the floating point to fixed point conversion on board.

Comment: I have read the application note. I assume that the computers signed numbers are what are given as Binary Two's Compliment in section 5?

Comment: I think the explanation might be easier to understand if the sentence "The zero point in such a device is at ... or 1.25V in this particular application" had a phrase, something like "we'll call this 0 point the 'mid-span'.". Also, it might be helpful to change 'midspan' to 'mid-span' for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

1. convert float to integer, by multiplying the float number. (multiplier must be high enough to get the complete resolution of the float.
2. add the average value of the integer signal to the signal ( or the highest absolute value)
3. use just the highest bits of the integer to satisfy the DAC

The DAC doesn't need negative values. The alternate component is still stored in the signal, but now with just positive numbers.